# Web design (responsive) page sizes in 2019

Tags: website-design

It's 2019. I am designing a web site (not developing). I am considering creating 3 layouts for each page:

- 375 x 667 (mobile)
- 1366 x 768 (laptop)
- 1920 x 1080 (large desktop)

I'm basing these sizes off of what I assume my clients audience will be using most. I recently started using Adobe XD for web design, and have also looked at Sketch. They seem to have different templates for desktop size pages, but I got my desktop size for XD.

Wondering if other designers have "go-to" web page sizes for different screens / breakpoints. Or do you customize the page sizes for each project?

Comment: I always find it odd that people think only in landscape. Having 2 27" screens here I always set a browser to be approx half a screen horizontally, giving me about an A4 portrait page. Even Stack Exchange's responsive design forgets this & forces you to remove all the irritating sidebar stuff so there's still some room for content in the middle..

Comment: As both a designer and developer, just a heads up: If your designers are also developers, designing 3 layouts makes sense. However, if they are not developers, I find that instead of designers creating one responsive layout in 3 versions, they actually end up designing 3 separate web sites, which makes development a challenge and leads to a lot of bloated front end code.

Comment: Also [Should the browser interface size be taken in to account when designing web apps?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/96258/23061)

Comment: "what I assume my clients audience will be using most" is a massive mistake. It's 2019 - there can be no assumptions. Seriously.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the idea that the content is the king. So the max size of the website _(or content area)_ should be whatever looks good with the content. Of course, there are exceptions, but generally if you can't "fill" the width of 1000px with your content in a sensible way, then don't... make the max width 600px or whatever. I design desktop first with `max-width` and handle breakpoints by reducing the viewport width and adding a breakpoint + adjusting css where needed. I've found this to work the best for me. If I'm lucky I may only need 1 breakpoint for mobile.

Comment: Marking a recent post about proper resolutions as a duplicate and referring to a post 4 years old makes it seem like you might not be the right person to moderate this topic. Now if you marked it in another way instead of as a duplicate, THAT might makes sense... The comments on this thread only further illustrate that this concept is a moving target and old info gets stale FAST.

Comment: @Rodger - OTOH, there is an advantage to *centralizing* the information on one version of the question. Instead of searching through multiple Q&As written over the years, people could - and should - **add updated answers to the original page**. (Though it is true that SE sites have no good way to indicate *timeliness*/obsolescence of answer.)

Comment: That last bit is the key issue. Something is marked correct, gets votted up X times, a new answer comes along, never gets votted correct, and likely never gets to the same count of votes because the people that know enough to vote it correct aren't looking at it. The people that need the info are unlikely to realize that what was correct and got many supporting votes is now effectively wrong. 

Insisting that we follow a system with an issue like this when it could be fixed by the admins simply changing the way it is enforced isn't helping, it is hurting.

Comment: The linked "already answered" proves that what you said doesn't work perfectly. This type of post has been flagged MANY times and pointed there and the least out of date info is 2016. IF the plan to "centralizing the information on one version of the question. Instead of searching through multiple Q&As written over the years, people could - and should - add updated answers to the original page" worked, this would be the poster child example of the perfect situation. I submit that it is the poster child that the plan doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Height is irrelevant.

I like to use [Zurb Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/) for responsiveness. It's much less "CSS-heavy" than other packages I've seen, such as Bootstrap. Foundation only offers the responsive grid and a *few* CSS stylings, rather than every pixel being styled (like Bootstrap).

Foundation uses 40em (min) and 64em (min) widths. On *very* rare occasions I'll set a third break point for 78em (min) for very large screens. But it's exceptionally rare that the 64em width fails to suffice.

If setting my own media queries in pixels, I typically use 3 breakpoints..

- 420px max
- 768px max
- 1200px max

Are these "correct"? Well, to each his own. They work very well for my projects. 
They may not for your projects. I don't really create a lot of full-blow web sites. I will on occasion. However, I mostly create a *great many* "landing pages", 3-page "squeeze" sites, or responsive emails.

My personal *opinion* is that you rarely want to go over 1200px. Because even if someone has a 2560px wide monitor they most probably are *not* displaying web pages at full screen. I know I *never* do. For my work, anything which needs to appear wider than 1200px is set to a 100% width and generally it's a background image or a color field. I actually am *annoyed* by websites that force a 1400px or wider display on a desktop. I find it kind of short-sighted to think that merely because a screen *can* display something wider, it's not very user-friendly to assume they *are* displaying pages at full screen widths on a (huge) desktop.

-- Not stating any of this is "how it has to be done" -- it's merely what works for me.

Comment: Scott ,If you go the SASS route and compile it yourself (I use grunt locally) leaving out non-required components, Bootstrap can get a lot lighter. I haven't used Zurb, but thought I'd point this out in case you hadn't considered it.

Comment: Yeah but SAS is more than what's needed here. I prefer to be more detailed in the CSS rather than use shortcuts. That is not to say SAS isn't worthwhile. It absolutely is for some environments. My issue with Bootstrap is that *it designs for you* and is really "over-templated" in my opinion. I mean, there's a reason all Bootstrap-driven sites look like Bootstrap-driven sites. And heaven forbid Twitter deciding to start charging for Bootstrap.

Comment: Then we mostly agree since I leave out most of what isn't grid, but especially in BS4 the grid is pretty invaluable, especially with all the flex shortcuts. Don't get me wrong, my sites don't look like Bootstrap ;) But I still find it saves time at the expense of reasonable weight (when compiled judiciously)

Comment: For me Foundation *starts* at a usable state without any need to strip anything. Just overwrite button, panel, callout, and body CSS (if desired) and it's golden.

Comment: I will check it out. I looked years ago, but always good to be reminded of new tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott, very helpful. One import part of the discussion are the grids being used. For example, if I am designing a page at 1920px wide, I plan to use a grid that might be around 1170 wide, 12 columns. No important content would fall outside of that, only full screen images and background colours. Although I've read that a grid should take up about 70% of a viewport width (ie if designing a 1920px wide page, use a grid that is 1344px wide). As you mentioned there are no hard and fast rules here, but do you have any additional thoughts on grids?

Comment: Well, Foundation uses a 12 section grid. So, yeah I use that a great deal. For desktop I tend to keep content in the middle 10 sections, sometimes 8. I, personally *never* design anything above 1200px. As stated in my answer, if it's more than 1200px wide, it's a color field or background mage, that's all. I ensure nothing *ever* **forces** the viewport to be wider than 1200px. The user can make it wider, but I don't design it wider.

Comment: That is to say, I do design the background to accommodate a wider than 1200px display, but there is zero actual content in anything outside of 1200px... hard to describe, but I'm sure you get it.

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want a size between mobile and desktop while you're designing.

Typically I use:
`@media all and (max-width: 1690px) { ...}`
`@media all and (max-width: 1280px) { ...}`
`@media all and (max-width: 980px) { ... }`
`@media all and (max-width: 736px) { ... }`
`@media all and (max-width: 480px) { ... }`
and try and make the elements fluid up to those break points.

I often end up on this page, where your next questions will probably be answered too! 
https://www.creativebloq.com/rwd/responsive-web-design-tutorials-71410085

Hope this helps.